# Can "publish_acl" and "subscribe_acl" be null in VerneMQ-MySQL plugin scenario?

Tags: mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

We are trying to implement database (MySQL) based authorization and authentication for our VerneMQ instance. We are successfully able to create clients with different set of "clientid-username-password".
What we are facing difficulties in is the topic subscription and publications. The broker poses some inconsistencies when receiving messages from clients when certain topic values are present in publish_acl and subscribe_acl fields. In the VerneMQ docs we see, the SQL DDL must have certain field (mountpoints, client_id, username, password etc) similarly publish_acl and subscribe_acl fields are also there. What we don't need is to limit the clients with certain publish and subscribe topic.

Is there a way we can bypass putting values in publish_acl and subscribe_acl field so that clients can publish and receive messages from/to any topic ?

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried putting wildcards ( e.g. `#` or `topic/foo/+/bar` ) in the fields?

Comment: @hardillb, Yes , Of course we have tried that. But again the problem is of inconsistencies in terms of messages received by the client.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the `publish_acl` and `subscribe_acl` fields empty will prevent clients from publishing or subscribing to any topic at all, respectively. I suggest, as well as the comment above, adding a `#` pattern to match any and all topics for both publish_acl and subscribe_acl fields.

I suspect the inconsistencies you've mentioned are not due to the patterns themselves. Checking the VerneMQ broker log will show you why a certain client was not being able to publish or subscribe. From my experience, the "inconsistencies" occur when you've just created/modified the ACL, but the VerneMQ broker was yet to load your ACL. There are configuration parameters that will help you to modify ACL caching behavior.

From the VerneMQ documentation (https://docs.vernemq.com/configuring-vernemq/db-auth)

> The database integrations will cache the ACLs when the client connects avoiding expensive database lookups for each publish or subscribe message. The cache entries are evicted when the client disconnects.

Usually reconnecting to the broker reloads the ACL when publishing or subscribing fails.

**The second option** is to use auth using the `file-auth` with topic authorization turned off. Clients will need a predefined username/password to connect, however, they can publish and subscribe to any topic. Documentation: https://docs.vernemq.com/configuring-vernemq/file-auth

**Alternatively**, you can modify the auth ACL plugin script so that it considers an empty field as a `#` pattern. You have to implement (Lua scripting) the `auth_on_register` hook.

Plugins documentation: https://docs.vernemq.com/configuring-vernemq/plugins

Here's an example: http://vernemq.com/blog/2016/04/29/vmq-diversity-the-vernemq-plugin-builder-toolkit.html